# pyinstaller makes huge sized file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller, xlwings

pyinstaller makes huge sized file(over 1.2GB).
I don't know why...
Is there any helper? Thank you.

Env
     Anaconda - Python 3.6.6

Imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
import xlwings as xw
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
```

Commands Tried

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile "./test.py" --name="test.exe"
pyinstaller -F "./test.py" --name="test.exe"
```

File List Starts with 'mkl' Sorted ASC by Size
[image]

Comment: not only that it probably doesnt work since you are not actually including any of the webdriver executables .... but thats way larger than it should be .. when i added those imports to a file and build an exe using pyinstaller in python2.7 it was 8.3 mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just Reinstall Anaconda.